# View only permission for community/site members for Wiki portlet is not working in Liferay

Tags: liferay, portlet, wiki, roles, portal

I have created a site where I have set two roles. Role 1 has been set to user1 with all permissions for Wiki and "VIEW" permission for user2 in Role2. But when I login as user2, I am able to edit the Wiki page. How do I restrict the user2 from editing, adding and modifying the content on the wiki.

P.S: User1 and User2 are members of site.

As mentioned in this Liferay forum, I removed the UPDATE permission for site members, but it is not working
https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/1199892

Comment: You mean you have removed UPDATE permission for site member while creating WIKI page? Which Liferay Version you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change permission for wiki by wiki-article:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!, Now trying to disable "Add child page" :(